# How can I navigate through a list on button click

Tags: python, streamlit

I am working on [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) how can I navigate through a list using a button click

**Example**

I have a list

```
import streamlit as st
lst =['a','b','c']
next = st.button('next',key='next')
for i in lst:
  if next:
    st.write(i)
```

How can I iterate through a list to print each element of list on button click? The code above just gives all the elements at once but I want for example: I press the button and it should print `'a'` then on another click it should print `'b'` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `st.session_state` in order to store the current index of the list to be shown! Learn more about it in [the docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state). Here's a working piece of code:

```py
import streamlit as st

my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
show_next = st.button("next")

# Initialize the current index
if "current_index" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.current_index = 0
   
# Whenever someone clicks on the button
if show_next:
    # Show next element in list
    st.write(my_list[st.session_state.current_index])
    # Update and store the index
    st.session_state.current_index += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the on_click parameter of button, as described here: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.button.

Example of how you could do anything on button click:

```
import streamlit as st

# this function is called when btn is clicked
def handleClick():
    # do anything here
    print("button clicked")

# create the button and set the on_click `callable` (aka function without ()).
btn = st.button('next', key='next', on_click=handleClick)
```

Example of how to iterate over and show list elements on click:

```
import streamlit as st

lst = [1, 2, 3]

def handleClick():
    for el in lst:
        print(el)

btn = st.button('next', key='next', on_click=handleClick)
```

If you want to display a different element of the list for each click, you need to keep track of what element to show next. As shown in this example:

```
import streamlit as st
 
cindex = 0 # tracks index to use
lst = [1, 2, 3]

def handleClick():
    print(lst[cindex])
    # update the index to use each click
    cindex = (cindex + 1) % len(lst)

btn = st.button('next', key='next', on_click=handleClick)
```

Comment: Thank you bu i am getting an error in the last snippet ** local variable 'cindex' referenced before assignment**

Comment: Is this exactly how you use the code snippet, or do you use it inside a class?

Comment: No it is exactly what i do please

Comment: Use the link at the top of my answer. Just like you can use on_click, you can also use args-.... in your button. This way you can pass arguments to you callable (handleClick). So then u can pass cindex (if it is out of scope).